# Spring boot can't find jsp in multi modules project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, http-status-code-404

I'm using spring boot and I decided just for example sake to split my project into modules. I have 4 modules, web, service, repository, domain. All work okay except JSP, spring can't find these pages. But when I didn't split my project to modules it worked. I didn't change configuration.

This is my structure of web module

[image]

Runner is located in web module, Here it is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool")
public class WebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false

spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
```

Parent POM xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
    <artifactId>newsmanagementparent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>newsmanagementparent</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modules>
        <module>repository</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>domain</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <module-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</module-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
                <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                <version>${module-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
                <artifactId>service</artifactId>
                <version>${module-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
                <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
                <version>${module-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
                <artifactId>repository</artifactId>
                <version>${module-version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And web POm xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
        <artifactId>newsmanagementparent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kz.epam.javalab.daimoncool</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I would be happy if you can help me) And I repeat, that it works when there were no modules, without changing the configuration, just adding modules it doesn't work.

> Result:

[image: Response Screenshot]

Also Intellij IDEA shows me that there is not view resolver for index.jsp, even though I add view resolver bean explicitly

Here is github link of project:
https://github.com/DaimonCool/newsmanagementmultimodules

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I use Intellij IDEA

Comment: Check your Deployment Assembly May be it will trying to find WebContent folder instead of webapp

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you using `:` instead of `=` in your `application.properties`?

Comment: Found on one site. I change to = but nothing happened

Comment: Create your build file and deploy from outside IDE, then verify

Comment: I don't have tomcat server, I use spring boot embedded tomcat

Comment: What URL are you trying to call?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: The problem is in module, when I create module for some reason it doesn't want to work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to change the working directory in intellij IDEA. Spring boot runner takes root path and then look for the jsp (in my case it was the parent project). But my runner was in web module, so I needed spring boot runner to change root path to web module (by changing the working directory), not to parent.

Comment: This has helped me a lot :))) Thanks!